# Product of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let A and B two bonded sets from $R$ i want to prove that the set $AB=\{ab,a\in A,b\in B\}$ is bounded

Let $c\in AB$ then there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $c=ab$ then $\inf(A)\times\inf(B)\leq c\leq \sup(A)\sup(B)$

Is this always  true? or one of sets must be in $R^+$ or the two?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ supposed to be bounded?

Comment: yes I will added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is not true in general. For example, consider $ A = \{ 1, -1 \}, B = \{ 2, 1 \}$.
We have $\inf (A) \times \inf (B) = -1 \times 1 = -1 > -2 \in AB $.

If both of the sets are positive, then your claim is true. Can you prove this?

---

To prove the general statement that you want, show that if $ A \subset [ -x, x ] $ and $ B \subset [ -y, y ]$, then prove that $ AB \subset [ -xy, xy ] $.

Comment: the two must be positive or just one of them?

Comment: I updated the example so that 1 set is positive, but the claim is still not true.

Comment: I don't understand what you added @Calvin lin

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: the second part

Comment: The second part is a claim that can help you prove the original statement that you have. I have not provided any proof of it. Can you prove it?

Comment: so if $A=[0,4[$ and $B=[-1,3]$ AB is not bounded?

Comment: I have no idea on how to prove it ?

Comment: No, that's not what you asked (nor what I am saying). You asked if "$\inf(A)\times\inf(B)\leq c\leq \sup(A)\sup(B)$", and that's not true in general. It doesn't imply that the set AB must be unbounded.

Comment: so is there an other way to prove the boudedness ?  if I understand my method is right if A and B are positive ?

Comment: the other way to prove boundedness is what I wrote below the line break (which is similar to the other answers). Yes, your method will work if A and B are also assumed to be positive.

Comment: I don't know how to prove it

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I let $z\in AB$ then there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ that is $-x\leq a\leq x$and $-y\leq b\leq y$ but I don't know how to do the product

Comment: That's good. Given that you're stuck, I'm presuming the possible signage is confusing you. If so, let's consider one (of 4) case where $ -x \leq a \leq 0$ and $ 0 \leq b \leq y$. Can you show that $ -xy \leq ab \leq 0 $?

Comment: yes I prove it, what are all the cases please?

Comment: Condition on whether the value is positive or negative. Total of $ 2 \times 2 = 4$ cases.

Comment: and this work only if $A\subset [-x,x]$ and $B\subset [-y,y]$  ? In general any to bounded sets in $R$ the product is bounded ?

Answer (score 0):

The inequalities you have written are not true in general: Take $A=\{0,1\}, B=\{-1\}$ and $c=0$.

If $A$ and $B$ are bounded then there exist $M,N \in (0,\infty)$ such that $|a| \leq M$ for all $a \in A$ and $|b|\leq N$ for  all $b \in B$. If $c=ab$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ the $|c|=|a||b| \leq MN$, so $C$ is bounded.

Comment: OP is not asking you to prove the original statement. OP is asking if the suggested approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

For your flaw see the answer of Calvin Lin.

Hint:

Find a positive constant $c$ such that $|a|\leq c$ and $|b|\leq c$ for every $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Now prove that $-c^2\leq ab\leq c^2$ for every $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.